# Ports for NAT'ed Windows share

Tags: samba, ports

Simple question: I have a NATed Linux at home that hosts a couple of samba shares. 
What Ports should I forward from the router to the Linux box so as to be able to access those shares from the internet with windows explorer (a la "\my.dyndns.org\shares\xxx" style)?
I want the **minimum** number of port openings that I should do in the router config to have read/write functionality.

EDIT: Client machine is a Vista one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **TCP 139**, "NetBIOS Session" – SMB wrapped in NetBIOS for compatibility
- **TCP 445**, SMB – the preferred method, SMB directly over TCP
- **ICMP Echo** (Ping) – used by Windows to check whether the machine is up.

---

"NetBIOS Name Service" is TCP/UDP 137, and "NetBIOS Datagram" is UDP 138, but you do *not* need any of these to connect to shares. These days it is only necessary for "network browsing", which only works within a LAN anyway.

Comment: Aha you're right. Although my 'answer' would have worked i think, I've edited it to the preferred solution. I still reckon openssh is a better way to go.

Comment: Vista has a problem making 445 work with forwarding. See my answer for a nice solution link about how to do CIFS over SSH on Vista.

Answer (score 3):

445 for tcp

Contrary to the original answer here, there's no reason to allow 137-139 which should be blocked.

However, **I strongly recommend you do not do this.** I don't think leaving a samba share internet-accessible is a good idea.

Please please please set up a secure solution such as an ssh server, so that you can scp/sftp data back and forth.

P.s. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017 seems to be a good reference of ports required by windows servers and http://www.petri.co.il/whats_port_445_in_w2k_xp_2003.htm explains the above a little more in depth.

Comment: Thanks I am so ** stupid, I ve been trying all day, but forgot UDP...

Comment: Also for the security issue I ll try to do it over ssh tunnels. Wouldnt be this secure enough?

Comment: ...btw, can ssh tunneling handle udp connections?

Comment: Tunneling samba through ssh is certainly possible, here's a guide: http://www.axllent.org/docs/networking/samba_over_ssh

Comment: I've edited my answer after grawity's answer as he makes a good point, even if my answer would have worked.

Comment: 139 is not for browsing... Older Windows versions use it for the SMB protocol, wrapped inside a NetBIOS session. So it has exactly the same security issues as 445 (raw SMB).

Comment: Bah leave me alone, I'm going back to Linux! :-) (post edited)

Comment: there is nothing wrong in opening WAN against TCP445 as long as you setup firewall to allow specifics

Comment: @mschr So in summary, there is something wrong with opening 445 on the wan unless you setup further restrictions. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

OK [here](http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/VistaLoopback.html) is a guide that could make my grandma do it in 5 mins. Worked without a glitch